# morphToMany column not found

Tags: laravel

I follow tutorial from laravel documentation but it seems the tutorial not complete to explain argument morphToMany to explicit determine what the function should point to.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'tagables.tagables_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tags`.*,
> `tagables`.`tagables_id` as `pivot_tagables_id`,
> `tagables`.`tag_tag_id` as `pivot_tag_tag_id`,
> `tagables`.`tagables_type` as `pivot_tagables_type` from `tags` inner
> join `tagables` on `tags`.`tag_id` = `tagables`.`tag_tag_id` where
> `tagables`.`tagables_id` = 1 and `tagables`.`tagables_type` =
> App\Models\Comic)

media table

```
    Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->mediumIncrements('media_id)->nullable(false);
         $table->string('title', 255);
    });
```

tags table // one row inside tag ( walking )

```
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->mediumIncrements('tag_id');
        $table->string('tag_name', 255);
    });
```

tagables table

```
    Schema::create('tagables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedMediumInteger('tag_id')->nullable(false);
        $table->unsignedMediumInteger('tagable_id')->nullable(false);
        $table->string('tagable_type', 255)->nullable(false);
    });
```

comic model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'tagable');
}
```

comic controller

```
   // insert new comic
    $comic = Comic::create([
        'title'         => 'Doraemon',
    ]);
   
   // Insert into tagables table with current comic id and bind to tag id 1 
   which is walking

   $comic->tags->create([
       'tag_id' => 1
   ]);
```

it succes to insert into media but failed to insert into tagables table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some mistakes in your code. Please try to rewrite this code. There is a working example of your code. I have checked it for you

2021_04_10_073813_create_media_table.php

```
 Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

2021_04_10_073837_create_tags_table.php

```
 Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

2021_04_10_073856_create_taggables_table.php

```
Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedMediumInteger('tag_id')->nullable(false);
        $table->unsignedMediumInteger('taggable_id')->nullable(false);
        $table->string('taggable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

class Media extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function medias()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Media::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

And finally in a some Controller

```
$media = Media::create([
            'name'         => 'media name1',
        ]);

        $tag = $media->tags()->create([
            'name' => 'tag name1',

        ]);
```

Comment: i fixed already in by looking other website, in comic controller i explicit fill pararementer inside morphToMany. `public function tags(){Tag::class, 'tagable', 'tagables', null, 'tag_id');`. now i have other problem,  i create my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032084/how-to-create-data-into-junction-table-many-to-many-relationship-without-create. but your answer still right answer. because i dont know tutorial is think reader to follow standart table. like id should id.