# How to create data into junction table many to many relationship without create data into the junction point to

Tags: laravel

It inserts both table inside tags and tagables, what i want is just to insert into tagables ( junction ) table. Cause before it insert into tagables, theres code to check first if tag will insert into tags table already exist or not, if exist just grab the id. To make it simple to my problem. i just don't include code to check if tags is exist or not.

post model

```
public function tags(){ return $this->morphToMany( Tag::class, 'tagable', 'tagables', null, 'tag_id ); }
```

post controller

```
// tags table theres a row id 1 with name greeting
$post = Post::create( ['body' => 'Hello World'] );
$post->tags()->create( ['tag_id' => 1] );
```

Tables

```
// posts table
$table->mediumIncrements('post_id');
$table->string('body');

// tags table
$table->mediumIncrements('tag_id');
$table->string('tag_name');

//tagables table
$table->unsignedMediumInteger('tag_id');
$table->unsignedMediumInteger('tagable_id');
$table->string('tagable_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way do this to start by creating the tag with the eloquent method 'firstOrCreate', and then when you already have a new tag or existing tag you can add this tag to a new Post. The code may look like something like this:

```
class Tag extends Model
   {
    

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable');
    }
   }

   

   

  $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(
            ['tag_name' => 'traveling'],
        );
    
        $post = $tag->posts()->create([
            'body' => 'My new interesting post',
    
        ]);
```

Comment: i use same parameter to explicit morphedByMany but it return unknown column. `Unknown column 'tag_tag_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `media_tags` (`media_type`, `tag_id`, `tag_tag_id`) values (3, 6, 1))` Error

 `return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class,'tagable', 'tagables', null, 'tag_id');`

Comment: and the problem with this way, how to input tag name multiple time? if 1 its okay, lets say theres 13 tags. `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` and so on

if the logic create tag first and later create post. it will create mutlti post.

Comment: $tag1 = Tag::firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => 'tag1'],
        );

        $tag2 = Tag::firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => 'tag2'],
        );

        $post = Post::create([
            'name' => 'tag name1',

        ]);
        $insertData = [
            ['tag_id' => $tag1->id, 'taggable_id' => $post->id, 'taggable_type' => Post::class],
            ['tag_id' => $tag2->id, 'taggable_id' => $post->id, 'taggable_type' => Post::class],

        ];
        Taggable::insert($insertData);

Comment: I have that mind too, use junction as model. but it will make awakward in model ways. use junction as model. I better use DB class to make clear model is.